# Авторизация и система ролей в ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, mvc

Создаю свой проект интернет-магазина на основе ASP.NET MVC 2 и столкнулся с проблемой создания пользователей и ролей. По-умолчанию, ASP хранит всю информацию в собственной базе данных, но меня такой подход не устраивает, т.к. я хочу хранить информацию о пользователях в собственной БД (чтобы потом связать каждого пользователя со своими покупками). 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, статьи о том, как проще это реализовать (статьи и ссылки на туториалы приветствуются)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При установке базы для аутентификации и ролей можно указать существующую БД, в которую и будут добавлены соответственные таблицы с хранимками.

Comment: Где и как это сделать?

Comment: Для примера: http://weblogs.asp.net/sukumarraju/archive/2009/10/02/installing-asp-net-membership-services-database-in-sql-server-expreess.aspx

Comment: А, это я знаю. Но как я понимаю, потом во всех последующих проектах в Visual Studio все роли и пользователи будут сохраняться в эту БД ?

Comment: Нет вы просто создаете структуру в необходимой БД, а потом указываете в web.config  строку подключения, ее же в свою очередь как провайдера membership.

Comment: Благодарю, то, что нужно:)